# How to use surplus credits?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have finished building all the levels, as time goes by, I have accumulated a lot of credits, how can I use them? I can't use them to build a new level and I don't know what else to do with them.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep saving for when there are new updates for Tiny Death Star. That way, you can get a headstart by buying 1 or more shops immediately when new updates arrive with more shops.

Comment: Amazing to see "Han" answer, is your surname by any chance Solo?

Comment: You could even stockpile Imperial items and complete the quests for more stockpiled money.

Comment: @Shadow That's what I'm doing.